# How to Trigger Windows Task Schedule restart after fails with python script

Tags: python, windows, error-handling, scheduled-tasks

I have a python script that when I find an error I throw sys.exit(1). This results in the task scheduler showing a "(0x1)" comment under last run result. A successful run returns "The operation completed successfully. (0x0)". Unfortunately though this does not trigger the task to be run again even though under setting I have the "if task fails, restart every:" checkbox checked. Any thoughts on how to improve this?

Another post has the following answer but I can not find where to put the custom filter? under the four settings; Create a Basic Task, When an Event is Logged, Action,Finish

You can,

1 activate history for Schedule (if not already)
2 on a History "Action completed" right click "Attached Task to This Event..."
3 Set a custom filter like this:

*[System[(EventID=201)]] and *[EventData[Data[@Name='ResultCode']='1']]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the task scheduler's event history is enabled, you can add a trigger for each exit code for which the task should be restarted. Trigger "on an event" with a custom XML query. The trigger should probably be delayed by at least 30 seconds to throttle attempts to restart the task.

Here's an example query. It looks for event ID 201 (action completed) with a task named "\PyTest" (use the full path, starting at the root "\" folder) and an exit code of 0xC000013A (i.e. `STATUS_CTRL_C_EXIT`, i.e. a console process killed by Ctrl+Break).

```xml
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
    <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
      *[System[EventID=201]] and 
      *[EventData[Data[@Name='TaskName']='\PyTest']] and
      *[EventData[Data[@Name='ResultCode']='0xC000013A']]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Comment: so where would I put this i m confused? Is this an entirely new task? Also i m assuming the only thing I change here is the PyTest to the name of the scheduled task?

Comment: Add a trigger to your *existing* task (not a new task). Modify my example query to use *your* task's name (use the fully-qualified path) and the exit code that indicates your task should be restarted.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. My path is 'C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Hamilton' and i've tried result codes '(0x1)', '0x1' and '1' and none seem to work. The other location i learned where task can be schedule C:\Windows\Tasks did not have my task there

Comment: I meant the tasks full path in the task scheduler library, not on disk. Normally users create tasks in the root folder of the library, such as my example `\PyTest`. The result code can be in decimal or hexadecimal. Also, make sure the task scheduler is creating events in the history tab.  If not, enable "all tasks history".